# How to disable gae python to check for updates every time I start a server in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I just hate seeing this for 20sec every time I run my server: `appcfg.py:393] Checking for updates to the SDK`.

Comment: Comment out the relevant lines in appcfg.py.  You even have the line number to start looking right in your question.

Comment: any clearer way to do this? google didn't set any settings or config files for this?

Comment: Well, look at the code in appcfg.py. Is it reading any config file before checking? If it is, that's the file. If not, then Wooble's solution is the only way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create or edit the file .appcfg_nag in your home directory. Edit the first line to be:

```
opt_in: false
```

Comment: Its not working in some computers like Enterprises, they remove username and user profile on reboot. How to make it work in those environment? (administrators remove on reboot the user home directory, if this way is used then every reboot i get same prompt)

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else looking for the answer, appcfg.py now has a command line switch:

```
--skip_sdk_update_check
```

happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

@Nick Jognson and @Joe answers both for me did not worked but here is how i fixed it for ENTERPRISES where user names get deleted and user profile gets deleted on every reboot.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE 
cmd = Popen('python.exe script.py', stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) 
out, err = cmd.communicate("sendNOnENTER\nsendNOnENTER\n")
print out
print err
```

Here script.py is executed and if it was asked to type Y or n you can use communicate method or second method is little bit nonsense but also works:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen
google_app_engine_update = 'c:/Python27/.appcfg_nag'
if os.path.exists(google_app_engine_update):
  target = open(google_app_engine_update, 'r+')
else:
  target = open(google_app_engine_update, 'w')

line1 = 'opt_in: false'
target.write(line1)
target.close()
Popen(['c:/Python27/python.exe', 'C:/google/devscript.py', arg1, arg2], shell=False)
```